# How to get a specific dictionary key value from ListDictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm implementing ListDictionary. I'd like to quickly get a particular item from that object without having to go through the entire thing with a loop.

Example:

```
ListDictionary myCol = new ListDictionary();
myCol.Add("totalCount", 5);
myCol.Add("filteredCount", 2);
myCol.Add("data", data); // Value of data here isn't relevant
```

Now, what I'd like to do is get the value of "totalCount" and use it like so:

```
int newCount = myCol["totalCount"] + 5;
```

But that doesn't compile with the error "Operator + cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'. If I try to cast it as a int, I get the exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How do I go about getting the actual value of that key?

Comment: I think you are better of using a dictionary with <string, int>

Comment: You get the actual value of the key by using `myCol["totalCount"]`, but it's an `object` so you have to convert it to an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably because the [Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) of a `ListDictionary` takes values of type `object`. This means your values are being boxed and unboxed. This means you will need to cast to the appropriate type. Try this instead:

```
int newCount = (int?) myCol["totalCount"] + 5 ?? 5;
```

This will try to convert `mycol["totalCount"]` to an int, but if it's null, it will just assign 5 to `newCount`

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qDJpEI)

Answer (score 0):

`Keys` and `Values` are type of object in `ListDictionary`.

You need to convert object to `int` type.

```
int newCount = Convert.ToInt32( myCol["totalCount"]) + 5;
```

**Note** - Consider using generic `Dictionary` if possible to avoid unnecessary conversion.